# ASSERT: "allArguments.size() == origArgc"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having this error in my Qt Application:

> Debug Error!
>   Program: C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\bin\QtCored.dll
>   Module: 5.1.1 File: global\qglobal.cpp
>   Line: 2014
>
> ASSERT: "allArguments.size() == origArgc" in file
>   kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 2095

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc,argv);
    qDebug()<<"argc:" << argc;
    qDebug()<<"arguments:"<<app.arguments().length();

    return 0;
}
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was passing arguments with a new line character in it.
After I removed, it worked again.

Comment: You mean from the command line, like `./runMyProgram "foo" "bar\n"` (possibly different syntax on Windows)? That should work, I'd think!

Comment: @BoBTFish actually I tried from QtCreator, I copied the arguments from a text editor (with line breaks) to the "Run > Arguments" field.